# Correct DB design to store huge amount of stock cryptocurrencies data in DB

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, nosql, bigdata

I want to store large amount of cryptocurrencies data in db. Then I want to show nice javascript price graphs with historical prices on webpage.
Problem is that I am not sure what database design is best for this problem, I was thinking about Mysql DB, but maybe NOSQL db are better in this case, I don’t know.

**What I need:**

- I need to track at least 100 crypto currencies with historical and
  current prices and other stock information like volume etc…
- I am going to insert new data every 10 minutes for each crypto ((6
  records / hour * 24h * 365 days) * 100 for each crypto = 5 256 000
  new records per year )
- I need to query various time ranges for each coin to draw graph on webpage.

**My idea:**

I came with this solution but I need to know if this is ok or I am completely wrong and naive.
In this case I would have 2 tables, first parent table where I would store all necessary info about coins, children table where would be all prices, but this child table would have to contain a huge amount of data, which is worrying me.

**My table structure example:**

*tbl_coin_detail:*

```
id.   |Tick_name    | Name      |Algorithm   |Icon  

1     | BTC         |Bitcoin    |SHA256      |path/to/img   
2     | ETH         |Ethereum   |Ethash      |path/to/img
.
.
.
```

*tbl_prices:*

```
id  | price_USD     | price_EUR | datetime              | Volume_Day_BTC        | FK_coin       

1   | 6537.2        | 5 632,28  | 2018-07-01 15:00:00   | 62121.7348556964      | 1

2   | 466.89        | 401.51    | 2018-07-01 15:01:00   | 156373.79481106618    | 2
.
.
.
```

Another idea is to make separate table for each coin prices, that would mean 100 tables with all historical and current prices and stock info instead of one huge table. 
I am really not sure here, what is better, all prices in one table are good for simple querying, but I guess it can be huge performance bottleneck, make queries from separated table will be worse for querying, because I will need to write query for each table but it can help with performance.

Can you point me to right direction how to solve this? SQL DB or NOSQL what is better? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: General rule: You can't choose an optimization strategy without knowing the queries you need to optimize for.

Comment: You might want to look into the PostgreSQL timescale extension.

Answer (score 4):

MySQL recommendations...

You have `Volume_Day_BTC`, yet you say "6 records/hour" -- is the record daily or more fine grained.

The volume of data is not that great, but it will be beneficial to shrink the datatypes before you get started.

`id` is unnecessary; use `PRIMARY KEY(coin, datetime)` instead.

Think carefully about the datatype for prices and volumes.  At one extreme is space (hence, somewhat, speed); at the other, precision.

```
DOUBLE -- 8 bytes, about 16 significant digits, large range
DECIMAL(17, 11) -- 8 bytes, limited to $1M and 11 decimal places (not enough?)
DECIMAL(26, 13) -- 12 bytes, maybe big enough?
etc.
```

Would it be OK to summarize data over, say, one month to save space?  Hourly or daily avg/hi/low, etc.  This would be very useful for speeding up fetching data for graphing.

In particular, I recommend keeping a Summary table by coin+day with volume, price, etc.  Consider using `FLOAT` (4 bytes, 7 significant digits, sufficient range) as more than good enough for graphing.

So, I am recommending 3 tables:

```
Coins -- 100 rows with meta info about the currencies.
Prices -- 5M rows/year of details -- unless trimmed  (400MB/year)
Summary -- 36500 rows/year for graphing range more than, say, a week. (4MB/yr)
```

It may be worth it to have an hourly summary table for shorter-range graphs.  There is no need to go with weekly or monthly summaries; they can be derived from the daily with sufficient efficiency.

Use InnoDB.

[*Summary tables*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables)

Comment: Hi Rick,thanks for valuable info. I didn’t know about summary tables. I was reading whole day about this problem, everybody pointing to aggregate time-series.I understand if I have 10 min. data in db, it is stupid to fetch them in chart with 3 months zoom, better is send 1 day data for example. I see coinmarketcap.com solve it somehow like this, zoom all for btc display 3days chart, 1 day zoom display 5 min chart. How to handle this zooming data.Do I need summary tables with 10min, hour, day, 3 day data.Do I need to aggregate data using mysql queries,like group by hour, day. Or other technique

Comment: The basic table has the 10min data.  3-data data can easily and efficiently be fetched from the day data.  They "zoom" by doing a new `SELECT` and plotting from scratch.

Comment: Hi Rick, I have one more question. In your answer you recommend to drop id (primary key) and use PRIMARY KEY(coin, datetime). If I understand it well, this is called composite primary key? What advantage bring this solution? Sorry for that I am not db expert. Thank you very much in advance for your time and answers:)

Comment: With InnoDB, the table is ordered according to the PK.  A Secondary key drills down a "BTree" to find the PK at the bottom.  Then the row is looked up by drilling down another BTree, namely one with the PK and data in the leaf nodes.  I don't know (without more info) whether it would be better to have PK(coin, dt) or PK(dt, coin).  Yes "composite".  Search for those terms; read more of my blogs; glance around this forum.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, that's far from 'huge'. We aren't talking billions of records here, so any properly indexed DB will do just fine.